# Azure Cosmos DB selecting min(int field) returning 0

Tags: c#, sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azureportal

Executing following SQL query against Azure Cosmos DB Collection always returning 0 from C# code.

```
SELECT value min([integer field]) FROM c
```

When running above query on the Azure portal - Data Explorer, sometime it returns expected number value of that particular field other time returns 0.

I am not sharing code intentionally because strange behavior is issue is not replicating when executing the same query against different collection (with same schema) on the Cosmos DB.

Comment: According to your description, I conducted a test, and I have not found the problem you described, whether it is seen in the tool or the code. Is there any problem with my reproduction method? I look forward to your reply.

Comment: Do you find another good way to solved the issue? And if my answer is not correct, we are very happy you can give us another solutions.^_^

Answer (score 0):

You can download [my demo](https://github.com/Jason446620/cosmos-dotnet-query) for test.

Data in my local cosmos.

[image]

Query in local. `https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html`.

[image]

Query by C# code.

```
            Console.WriteLine("Beginning operations...\n");
            CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient("https://localhost:8081/", "C2***w==");
            Database database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync("ToDoList");
            Container container = database.GetContainer("jason");
            // Query for an item
            FeedIterator <dynamic> feedIterator =  container.GetItemQueryIterator<dynamic>("SELECT value MIN(c.age) from c");
            while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                FeedResponse<dynamic> response = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync();
                foreach (var item in response)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
            }
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your all help your demo looks similar to my db. I have database in Azure portal though not sure if that causing the issue. And for C# I have chosen a work around for this issue for now, whenever I get time I will go back to my code and see if I have made any mistake in my code.. Thanks again for looking into this matter!